# Why is it that when I try to overlay a PIL image onto another, both of which have the same size, they end up not aligning properly?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This is my test frame, I am trying to find which map it is by pasting every single map on top and checking if the images match.
It is cut perfectly and the image I paste on top is also cut perfectly but I am getting this result:

[image: TEST FRAME] [image: RECOLORED MAP IMAGE]

Why am I getting this behavior and how to fix it? This is my code:

```
bottom_image = Image.open("test_frames/test_frame_20.png").convert("RGBA")
top_image = Image.open("../map_images/split.png").convert("RGBA")
lower_hsv = np.array([0, 0, 122])
upper_hsv = np.array([174, 53, 130])

top_image = top_image.resize((bottom_image.size[0], bottom_image.size[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)

img_array = np.array(top_image)
img_array[..., :3] = [255, 0, 0]

best_result = 9**999
rotation_degrees = 0
red_image = Image.fromarray(img_array)

for i in range(1, 5):
    red_image_copy = red_image.copy().rotate(i*90)
    result_image = Image.alpha_composite(bottom_image.convert("RGBA"), red_image_copy)
    numpy_array = np.array(result_image)

    opencv_image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(opencv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_hsv, upper_hsv)
    result = np.sum(mask)

    if result < best_result:
        best_result = result
        rotation_degrees = i*90

print(rotation_degrees)
result_image = Image.alpha_composite(bottom_image, red_image.rotate(rotation_degrees))
result_image.save("result_image.png")
```

Just want to repeat that both images are cut perfectly and theres no space to the left and right on the image I paste on top.

Links to download both images i use:

map: https://ibb.co/bH8K5Ty
test_frame: https://ibb.co/fMRqN3s

Comment: [mre] required. please present pictures that are *actually* the same size, and oriented properly. your ibb.co links show a 354x334 image and an 894x952 image.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz the code resizes it to the same size as the frame image and rotates it in the for cycle. That is also my question. It resizes it to the same size but its not indentical. I cannot just resize the top image because sometime the frames will have different sizes of the map and I need it to be done dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input pictures aren't the same size. One is significantly larger.

They are almost square, but not really. One is 894x952 (tall), the other is 354x334 (wide).

One of your input pictures is rotated by 90 degrees relative to the other.

You swapped, or rather *failed* to swap, the width and height before the resize operation.

The resize operation then squashed the picture in one direction and stretched it in the other.

Please step through your code with a debugger and also inspect the results of every operation.

Comment: The only line in code where I resize is this:
```top_image = top_image.resize((bottom_image.size[0], bottom_image.size[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)```
I replaced it with ```top_image.resize(bottom_image.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)``` but still same result. If I swap the width and height I will just get an Error because of ```Image.alpha_composite```

Comment: I have edited my answer a few times. please re-read it. then investigate your code. it's not an issue with opencv or PIL, it's an issue of logic. please debug your code. that's not a request. that is a requirement of questions on SO. [ask], [mre].

Comment: The problem was that since the map is not a square, when rotated it would actually leave some space on top and bottom. Thus the only solution would be to have 4 images of each rotations of the map so they can be cut perfectly instead of rotating with code.